# How to redistribute Managed DirectX?

Tags: managed-directx

I've developed an app which uses the Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D namespace. The app runs on computers which have the Managed DirectX SDK installed, but not on those which have only the usual DirectX.

Specifically, it complains that it "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D [...]".

What's the best way to redistribute the necessary assemblies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply use the redistributable installer for mdx provided by microsoft. it will install the native dx as well as managed extensions.

Comment: Could you please point at this "redistributable installer for mdx", as I can't find one?

Comment: Sorry, wrong link the first time.  This is the correct link: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=886ACB56-C91A-4A8E-8BB8-9F20F1244A8E&displaylang=en

Comment: Note that the DirectX redistributable is updated every few months.  As of today (March 19, 2009), the November 2008 version is the latest.  You can find the latest version linked from this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/directx/aa937788.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you do redistribute the MDX libraries, be aware that this is no longer supported by Microsoft and has been deprecated in favour of XNA.  You might also want to look at [SlimDX](http://code.google.com/p/slimdx/) as an alternative